# How to console.log a parameter of a JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript

In this example I have a function named `somar` which returns the sum of `numA` and `numB` and after that, the console shows me the result of the sum:

```js
let somar = (numA, numB) => { //função anônima JS

  console.log("Somando " + numA + " com " + numB);
  return numA + numB;
}

var resultado = somar(10, 5);
console.log(resultado);
```

When I run this code, my output obviously is 15.
But how do I `console.log` `numA` and `numB`?

When I tried to console log `numA` and `numB` my output is `undefined`.

I just got the expected result when I used the `console.log` inside the function as shown in the example. But how to do it outside?

Comment: _"When I tried to console log numA and numB"_ - where?

Comment: They don't _exist_ outside of the function, those are just the parameter names _inside_ the function.

Comment: This logs the parameters just fine. `numA` and `numB` are local to `somar` and cannot be accessed outside of it.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Thx for the link, gonna read that.
And about ur question, i didn't post it the part *where* i tried 
but it was something like ```console.log("Somando" somar.numA);```
But, didn't worked either
I think i have to study more about function scopes

Comment: @DaveNewton The example is of what actually works: _I just got the expected result when I used the console.log inside the function as shown in the example. But how to do it outside?_

Comment: You are passing those parameters to that function, so you already have them, just put them on a variable before passing them to that function